# Are GROUPS and ROLES the same thing in OpenDJ LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap, opendj

I have managed to create a hierarchy structure which has 
three Organizational units namely :

ou=People || ou=Groups || ou=Role (Theses are three differernt  nodes under a baseDN)

Under people I have users entry (e.g edanny), each entry having the objectClass = inetOrgPerson. Under Groups I have entries (e.g Inventory Dept.) having objectClass = groupOfUniqueNames and lastly under Role (e.g Admin) the entries have objectClass = organizationalRole.

Are the above entries the right way to organize a hierarchy in LDAP which requires People group, Role and Organization's Dept. ?

Further I have associated each user under *People Unit* with Roles and Groups in their own attributes roleOccupant and uniqueMember respectively rather than writing each user's role and groups in the user's entry.

Is it the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way.  I would suggest that you Remove the Role group and add members ( in the Groups (basically these will be your roles)

And then you can add the Department of each user as an attribute of each individual user.

If the attributes of  the objectclass inetOrgPerson are not enough you can also add more objectclasses or you can create your own

So in the end you will have your Users under ou=People and your roles under ou=Groups

Its not a right or wrong type of question, it can be done using your way, but it will be easier i think to follow the above

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually in my project the departments are not in the same line rather they are hierarchical. Some thing like this:

[ Dept1 -> (has) computer lab -> Library ]
[ Dept2 -> (has also) computer lab -> Library ]
....

So you see I need to maintain a hierarchical structure in the LDAP. 
But if I write a user belongs to which dept. (keeping in mind that hierarchical structure) as a user's attribute, I have to finish it up using a name having comma separated values like Dept1,computerlab,library (attribute value)